# Magento 2: Change Upsell text: We found other products you might like!

Tags: magento2, upselling

For upsell products in Magento2, how can edit the text above the upsell products that says: **"We found other products you might like!"**

I would like it to say "Customers also viewed"

Comment: We can found this text in: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`. However, I think the new text is different meaning from the old one. Is there a specific reason for this change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With Custom Theme:**

Override `items.phtml` in your theme, Copy `items.phtml`

**From:**

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

**To**

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/produc‌t/list/items.phtml`

Now change

```
$title = __('We found other products you might like!');
```

to

```
$title = __('Customers also viewed');
```

Flush cache and try.

**With Custom Module:**

Create `catalog_index_index.xml` at `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list/items.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Copy** `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml` **to** `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

Now change

```
$title = __('We found other products you might like!');
```

to

```
$title = __('Customers also viewed');
```

Flush cache and try.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, none of the other answers have ever really been right. They might work but that's not the way to change text.

When you find text in a template wrapped like `__('We found other products you might like!');` this means it's controllable by the language file.

I've found that usually the language file in the theme is enough, so in: `app/design/frontend/<VENDOR>/<THEME_NAME>/i18n/`, find your language CSV file, find the text you want to change and add the change. If the text isn't in that file, most times I've tried, just adding it into the file works.

Comment: You are right. Well done, mate!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite template **vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml** line 80 from

```
$title = __('We found other products you might like!');
```

to

```
$title = __('Customers also viewed');
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but here is a different approach than already suggested:

The $title is already inside a translatable string, therefore instead of over-riding the entire items.phtml file, you can add a translation file (.csv) inside your theme. Over-riding the entire file should be avoided when it's not absolutely needed as it can be hard to spot if an update to that file has been added with any further updates.

Place your translation file here:

Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_GB.csv

With the contents:

"We found other products you might like!","Customers also viewed"

This can be changed for any locale your site has.